# Cakephp vendor files load

Tags: cakephp

I have problem with Paylane rest client and Cakephp 3.
Via console and composer I download Paylane rest client:

https://packagist.org/packages/paylane/client

```
composer require paylane/client
```

Ok, now I try to call this class.

```
require_once(ROOT .DS. 'vendor' . DS  . 'paylane' . DS . 'client' . DS . 'paylane' . DS . 'PayLaneRestClient.php');
$client = new PayLaneRestClient('aaaaa', 'aaaaaa');
```

But I still have error:

> Call to undefined function Controller\PayLaneRestClient()

How I can resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can resolve this ?

It is `new \PayLaneRestClient('aaaaa', 'aaaaaa');` pay attention to the missing \ in front. But it is best practice to add classes via the `uses` statement on top of the file.

In the case this was not just a typo, you're a few years late to the party and want to learn about namespaces in php http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: really?! I searched all the blogs page and nothing. And this is such a trifle. Thank you